# Make the notification LED color editable (and allow me to disable it)!

Tags: feature-request, notifications, android-app

I really like notifications for new inbox items. But I'd highly prefer it to only vibrate and play a sound that only plays for notifications from the SE app.

Right now the LED seems to turn white or green depending on the kind of notification whenever one arrives. However, a green LED is also used for new Facebook messages (which is another app with no option to change the color).

Anyway, there should be an option to:

- disable LED notifications altogether
- change the color for LED notifications
- change the duration of the LED notification (automatically turn it off again after some time)

Comment: Duration as in the length of a single flash if the LED is flashing/blinking, or as in some auto-dismiss after *x* minutes? (Not using the app; no idea if the LED blinks or not.)

Comment: You get all the fun, iPhone got no such cool things!

Comment: That might be phone specific.Darn it, I now need to try it on my old phone (with a 3 colour LED), and my current phone only has a white LED.

Answer (score 7):

Download an app called [lightflow](http://www.folioflow.com/ff/home/website/lightflow). It allows customization of LED notification lights on Android.

Comment: I've added a link to the liteflow home page - I wanted to add a link to the google play page, but there seem to be two versions, lite and normal.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It was one of first posts. Didn't look into adding links yet ha.